# Problems with newline parameter in numpy savetxt function

Tags: python, numpy

Having the structured array like this :

`[ (b'H', 0.9425, 0.1412, 7.1414) ... (b'N', 1.0037, 4.0524, 6.8000)]`

I want to make a `.txt file` using `numpy.savetxt` where each element of the array is written in separate line:

```
H   0.9425   0.1412   7.1414
N   1.0037   4.0524   6.8000
```

I set the `newline='\n'` but it doesn't work properly and all the elements are written in single line. The same problem with ***header*** parameter, the specified header is also printed in the same line.

Now it looks like this:

```
29Shifts: 1.0  3.0  7.0b'C' 1.0029  3.5098  7.9883 b'N' 1.0039  4.0586  6.8008 
29Shifts: 1.0  4.0  0.0b'C' 1.0029  4.5078  0.9873 b'N' 1.0039  5.0586  -0.2000
29Shifts: 1.0  5.0  9.0b'C' 1.0029  5.5078  9.9844 b'N' 1.0039  6.0586  8.7969
```

Here are the parameters used:

```
np.savetxt(outfile, recarray, fmt=[b'%s','%-7.4f','%-7.4f','%-7.4f'], delimiter='  ', newline='\n', header='29\nShifts: 1.0 1.0 3.5\n', comments='')
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you print juste 2-3 lines of raw data ? Not an array please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if there's a problem with `\n` on your system; maybe Python is using one value, while your file viewer is expecting another (there are dos, linux, and mac standards).

I have no problem with this data and format in an Ipython session on a linux machine.

```
In [88]: d=[ (b'H', 0.9425, 0.1412, 7.1414),(b'N', 1.0037, 4.0524, 6.8000)]
In [89]: data=np.array(d,'|S1,f,f,f')
In [90]: data
Out[90]: 
array([(b'H', 0.9424999952316284, 0.1412000060081482, 7.14139986038208),
       (b'N', 1.0037000179290771, 4.0524001121521, 6.800000190734863)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4')])

In [91]: np.savetxt('test.txt', data,fmt =[b'%s','%-7.4f','%-7.4f','%-7.4f'])

In [92]: cat test.txt
b'H' 0.9425  0.1412  7.1414 
b'N' 1.0037  4.0524  6.8000 

In [93]np.savetxt('test.txt', data,fmt=[b'%s','%-7.4f','%-7.4f','%-7.4f'], 
  delimiter='  ', newline='\n', header='29\nShifts: 1.0 1.0 3.5\n', comments ='')

In [94]: cat test.txt
29
Shifts: 1.0 1.0 3.5

b'H'  0.9425   0.1412   7.1414 
b'N'  1.0037   4.0524   6.8000
```

Comment: actually, I set `newline='\r\n'` and it works now. I used simple windows notepad to open the file. but I don't understand why `newline='\n'` doesn't work. btw, with `newline='\n'` I can open file in UEDIT32 and then there is no problem.

Comment: Windows uses 2 characters at the end of a line, a 'return' and a 'newline'.  Unix uses only one.  Python running on Windows should be aware of this and use the double character.  But a file written on a Linux machine may need to be converted if transferred to Windows.  But better editors can handle either style (or the MAC one).

Comment: ok, now I get it. one small question in addition. how to get rid of the b signs before letters? Because I'd like to have this kind of line **H  0.9425   0.1412   7.1414**. Do I have to replace the first column with the new one obtained by editing the old one with `.decode('UTF-8')` method? Thank you

Comment: The `b` marks a byte string in Python3, where unicode is the default.  It corresponds to a `'S'` dtype.  `loadtxt` and `savetxt` open their files in byte mode.  Are you seeing the `b` in the file, or in the Python session?

Comment: I see them both in file and python session